# Android webservice library with authentication support?

Tags: android, web-services

I'm quite new to software development on Android. For now, I'm using MonoDroid because I'm quite comfortable with C# as a development language, but I'm also proficient in Java.

I'm currently looking into developing an Android app that consumes a webservice that requires authentication. However, the amount of information that is available on the subject is tremendous, and a lot of it seems outdated as well. I've seen RESTful webservices, kSOAP and various other libraries. And it confuses the hell out of me.

So, considering I am going to start from scratch, what approach would be best here? Should I make a SOAP based webservice? Or a RESTful one? And how do I do authentication, preferable over https? I've done some WCF services before, and that worked if I used the built-in authentication layers, but I can only assume that on Android, most of the WS* stuff is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using RESTful web services if you're starting from scratch. It's more lightweight and much easier to use on Android. Google doesn't support SOAP based services, so you have to rely pretty much on A. kSoap for Android or B. some custom soap solution you write.

My personal experience is that kSoap is a huge pain to use, especially if complex data structures, authentication and https is involved. You can give it a try, but I think you'll quickly find yourself digging through the kSoap source, to find the solution for some cryptic problem. Documentation beyond the basics is practically nonexistent for that project. Also, SOAP is a ridiculously bloated protocol for a mobile device IMO.

So I'd go with restful services, using XML or JSON to transmit data.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with KSOAP and its pretty easy to use. I also use ws for authenticating and have no problems as such. YOu could always start out with SOAP as its pretty easy and would find lot of examples for ksoap.

Answer (score 0):

I did have success with http://jcifs.samba.org/ running on Android. Unfortunately, I dont have the source code to share any more as we moved to a different authentication method completely (loads of custom stuff basically).

I found that project through the following link: http://danhounshell.com/blog/android-using-ntlm-authentication-with-httpclient/

There is also another NTML project for AD integration which might help (i have no experience):

http://www.ioplex.com/jespa.html